# Why doesn't a Groovy closure have access to injected class member?

Tags: groovy, closures, guice

We are using Groovy and Guice on a project and I came across the following error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myService for class: com.me.api.services.SomeService$$EnhancerByGuice$$536bdaec

Took a bit to figure out, but it was because I was referencing a private class member, that was injected, inside of a closure. Can anyone shed any light as to why this happens?

Furthermore, is there any better way of doing this?

Here is a snippet of what the class looks like:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class MyService extends BaseService<Thing> {

    @Inject
    private ThingDao thingDao

    @Inject
    private OtherService<Thing> otherService

    @Override
    List<Thing> findAll() {
        List<Thing> things = this.dao.findAll()

        things.each { 
            //Note: This doesn't work!
            otherService.doSomething()
        }

        things
    }
```

I either have to use a standard for loop or not use the injected member which then tends to lead to code duplication.

Comment: Nothing really to do with Guice.  The field is `private`, so Groovy doesn't generate an accessor for it.

Comment: In plain Groovy, private class fields are accessible from closures. But, keep in mind the private field is being injected to the *class* instance, not the closure. The closure's resolve/delegation strategy comes into play something needs to be looked up within a closure. Try posting an example which demonstrated your problem more thoroughly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TLDR;

Either declare `otherService` public (remove `private` modifier) or add a getter `OtherService<Thing> getOtherService(){otherService}`

If you *absolutely* want to avoid exposing the field through a property, you can do the following trick: create a local variable outside the Closure scope that references your service:

```
OtherService<Thing> otherService=this.otherService
things.each { 
        //Note: This will work! Because now there is a local variable in the scope. 
        //This is handled by normal anonymous inner class mechanisms in the JVM.
        otherService.doSomething()
}
```

## Explanation

Under the hood, your closure is an object of an anonymous class, not the object that has your private field, `otherService`.

This means that it can't resolve a direct reference to the field. Accessing a symbol inside the closure will first look at local variables, and if no match is found, the `getProperty()` method in `Closure` will be called to find a property, depending on the resolution strategy that you defined. By default, this is `OWNER_FIRST`.

If you look the code of `Closure#getProperty`:

```
        switch(resolveStrategy) {
            case DELEGATE_FIRST:
                return getPropertyDelegateFirst(property);
            case DELEGATE_ONLY:
                return InvokerHelper.getProperty(this.delegate, property);
            case OWNER_ONLY:
                return InvokerHelper.getProperty(this.owner, property);
            case TO_SELF:
                return super.getProperty(property);
            default:
                return getPropertyOwnerFirst(property);
        }
```

You see that the owner, delegate and declaring objects need to have matching **properties**.

In groovy, if you declare a field `private`, you won't get auto-generated accessor methods, so no properties will be publicly exposed for outside objects.